# Finding date gap between two timeframe

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am required to find out the loss duration when the machine is running but not running any load. The machine is able to run several load concurrently which creates a lot of overlapping datetime.

Gantt Chart illustration of my task:

[image]

Sample Table Structure

```
+-----------+------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| Equipment | Type | State |    Tracked_inTIME   |   Tracked_outTIME   | Load_Type |  
+-----------+------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| A1        | MACH | UP    | 2018-11-13 08:00:00 | 2018-11-13 10:00:00 | NULL      |  
| A1        | LOAD | NULL  | 2018-11-13 08:20:00 | 2018-11-13 09:43:00 | PROD      |  
| A1        | LOAD | NULL  | 2018-11-13 08:22:30 | 2018-11-13 09:55:00 | PROD      |  
| A1        | LOAD | NULL  | 2018-11-13 08:30:00 | 2018-11-13 10:11:00 | PROD      | 
| A1        | MACH | DOWN  | 2018-11-13 10:00:00 | 2018-11-13 10:35:00 | NULL      |  
| A1        | MACH | UP    | 2018-11-13 10:35:00 | 2018-11-13 15:11:00 | NULL      |  
| A1        | LOAD | NULL  | 2018-11-13 11:00:00 | 2018-11-13 11:51:00 | PROD      |  
| A1        | LOAD | NULL  | 2018-11-13 11:25:00 | 2018-11-13 11:55:00 | PROD      |  
| A1        | LOAD | NULL  | 2018-11-13 12:05:00 | 2018-11-13 14:11:00 | PROD      |  
| A1        | LOAD | NULL  | 2018-11-13 12:25:00 | 2018-11-13 13:05:00 | PROD      |  
| A1        | LOAD | NULL  | 2018-11-13 13:45:00 | 2018-11-13 15:11:00 | PROD      |  
| A2        | MACH | UP    | 2018-11-13 08:00:00 | 2018-11-13 14:05:00 | NULL      |  
| A2        | LOAD | NULL  | 2018-11-13 08:00:00 | 2018-11-13 14:05:00 | PROD      | 
+-----------+------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Wrong Output (Column: Gapduration = 40 , should be 0 as the machine is still running a load)

```
    +----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-------------+
    | EQ | State |      EQ_inTIME      |     EQ_outTIME      |     LOAD_inTIME     |     LOAD_outTIME     | GapDuration |
    +----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-------------+
    | A1 | UP    | 2018-11-13 08:00:00 | 2018-11-13 10:00:00 | 2018-11-13 08:20:00 |  2018-11-13 09:43:00 |          20 |
    | A1 | UP    | 2018-11-13 08:00:00 | 2018-11-13 10:00:00 | 2018-11-13 08:22:30 |  2018-11-13 09:55:00 |           0 |
    | A1 | UP    | 2018-11-13 08:00:00 | 2018-11-13 10:00:00 | 2018-11-13 08:30:00 |  2018-11-13 10:11:00 |           0 |
    | A1 | DOWN  | 2018-11-13 10:00:00 | 2018-11-13 10:35:00 | 2018-11-13 08:30:00 |  2018-11-13 10:11:00 |           0 |
    | A1 | UP    | 2018-11-13 10:35:00 | 2018-11-13 15:11:00 | 2018-11-13 11:00:00 |  2018-11-13 11:51:00 |          25 |
    | A1 | UP    | 2018-11-13 10:35:00 | 2018-11-13 15:11:00 | 2018-11-13 11:25:00 |  2018-11-13 11:55:00 |           0 |
    | A1 | UP    | 2018-11-13 10:35:00 | 2018-11-13 15:11:00 | 2018-11-13 12:05:00 | *2018-11-13 14:11:00 |          10 |
    | A1 | UP    | 2018-11-13 10:35:00 | 2018-11-13 15:11:00 | 2018-11-13 12:25:00 |  2018-11-13 13:05:00 |           0 |
    | A1 | UP    | 2018-11-13 10:35:00 | 2018-11-13 15:11:00 | 2018-11-13 13:45:00 |  2018-11-13 15:11:00 |          40 |
    | A2 | UP    | 2018-11-13 08:00:00 | 2018-11-13 14:05:00 | 2018-11-13 08:00:00 |  2018-11-13 14:05:00 |           0 |
    +----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+-------------+
```

- Output was derived by doing a self join to bind the load time frame to equipment state.
- The load_inTIME at the first row of every equipment state change is compared with the equipment_inTIME
- Subsequent rows of load_inTIME are compared to the previous load_outTIME using the lag() function
- The main problem that I had was that there was a load timeframe (marked with *) which spans over multiple load duration that my calculation did not manage to account for

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems like the machine can run several load's on the same time ? Any algoritm for this ? any limits ?  Would be nice to setup  job-start/job-end collums pre-predicted

Comment: I don't understand what the red is on the Gantt chart, nor exactly what results you want.

Comment: Pardon me. Red stands for the duration when the machine is down. I am trying to find out the duration where there is no load going into the machine even when the machine is operational (up state) .

Answer (score 0):

Almost answered too quickly. Sorry if the other answer gets through. I didn't see your comments below the 2nd table.

Soooo, I think you need to modify your table a bit, not to change it, but get an interim dataset to work with (CTE/temp table/etc...). You need to get your data to represent what you're seeing on your chart with regard to the large black lines that span top to bottom across both load and mach timelines.

Essentially, you should have one contiguous series of time represented. This is what the large black lines are asking for. When load start/stops, those times should be in series with your mach up/down times. For every record you compare the current records "Tracked_outTIME" against the next records (lead function) "Tracked_inTIME". If > then end the current records "out" time with the next records "in" time and create a flag to say "is_loaded". You'll use this in a next/final query to query your new time sequence table to get your datediff when transition from is_loaded = 1 to is_loaded = 0 or vice versa.

So, your first "mach up" records should not go to 10, but should end at 8:20 when load begins.... and so on and so on to create your new/temp table. then query that table.

Comment: I realised that I should elaborate more on the issue which I had added in my edit. 
 
The main problem I had was that there will be some load that ran way longer than other load which made the particular timeframe overlaps multiple times. Therefore even though there is a 40min gap difference between load_out & the next load_in time, it should not be accounted for as the machine is still running the particular load which I mentioned at the beginning.

Can u elaborate more on solving this particular issue?

Comment: I've slept since I last thought about this and have changed my mind a bit. This is better suited to using a time dimension table. First create a table that holds a record for every second in a day (80k records), you can then join your table of mach time and load times against this date dimension to set a "machup/machdown" property and a "loadon/loadoff" property for every second in the day. You can just sum the count of records (or seconds) where machup and loadoff.

Comment: You seem fairly familiar with SQL and lead/lag functions already so, Im hoping you an see the solution from there. There are a number of ways to do this, but I think the key here is that you will have a very hard time trying to do this in one query and having that one query go against your raw source table (with mach and load times unlinked or not "merged" onto a single timeline. My first suggestion would work (I think) but the query was getting uglier and uglier. If you work with the type of data you are in this problem, you'll benefit from having some date and time dimension tables around.